# Unable to include css and js references in JSP

Tags: html, css, jsp, tomcat7, eclipse-juno

I am trying to add css and js reference libraries into the jsp page, but getting the error `404: file not found`.

I tried many different ways given at various sites and posts, but could not resolve the issue.

Here is the project structure:

[image]

My `web.xml` is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <display-name>SchoolERP</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>SchoolERP</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.rms.school.controllers.ControllerHome</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>SchoolERP</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/ERP</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>ERP</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

Main servlet `ControllerHome.java` contain following code:

```
@WebServlet({ "/", "/home" })
public class ControllerHome extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("jsp/template.jsp");
        request.setAttribute("content_page", "welcome.jsp");
        rd.forward(request, response);

    }
}
```

and `header.jsp` file contain following code:

```
<%@page import="com.rms.school.utils.Config"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<%
String title = request.getParameter("title");
if(title==null){
    title = "Untitled";
}%>
<title>
<%=title %>
</title>
<link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/ndt-custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/menu-styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

<!-- HTML5 shim for IE backword compatibility-->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js">
        </script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>
```

`welcome.jsp` is simple file containing following code:

```
<h1>WELCOME !</h1>
```

And `footer.jsp` in `jsp/include` folder contain all closing tags for `body` and `html`.

I tried includeing files using tag libraries too. But still problem not resolved.

When I see the output page at `http://localhost:8080/SchoolERP/`, it is giving the error in firebug as:

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:8080/SchoolERP/css/bootstrap.css"
```

Whereas the `page source` shows the `head` section as follows:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">


<title>
Untitled
</title>
<link href="/SchoolERP/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="/SchoolERP/css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="/SchoolERP/css/ndt-custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="/SchoolERP/css/menu-styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

<!-- HTML5 shim for IE backword compatibility-->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js">
        </script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
```

When I click on file link in this source, I get error as:

[image]

Please help me to know where and what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is your template.jsp page inside css folder? From your folder structure its outside i guess. check the file path everything included correctly? CSS, js,img, jsp pages were in appropriate folder but you linked like under css - > jsp pages were there.. If you change it the page might work :)

Comment: `css` and `jsp` are folders in `WebContent`. All `.css` files are in `css` folder. `template.jsp` and `welcome.jsp` are in `jsp` folder. Whereas `header.jsp` and `footer.jsp` are in `css/include/` folder. But I am giving all paths to source files (`.css` and `.js`) w.r.t root using `pageContext.request.contextPath`. All text in those jsp files is getting loaded. But the css and js files are not getting applied (included).

Answer (score 0):

Finally after long search and try, we got to the problem's root cause...

The annotation above the servlet class `@WebServlet({ "/", "/home" })` was actually causing the problem.. I just removed it and problem is resolved.

In fact, this annotation was not necessary, as it was already added as a part of `web.xml`.